# mySQL - combining data / sum of total

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which is pulling through some orders in a database:

```
SELECT company, amount, total  FROM cscart_order_details
INNER JOIN cscart_orders
ON cscart_order_details.order_id = cscart_orders.order_id
 WHERE 
    date(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`)) >= ADDDATE(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL -6 DAY)
```

This produces the following information:

```
|company | | amount | | total  |
================================
| NTE001 | |   1    | | 51.06  |
| NTE001 | |   1    | | 126.76 |
| NTE001 | |   1    | | 126.76 |
| EUR004 | |   1    | | 832.13 |
| EUR004 | |   1    | | 832.13 |
| EUR004 | |   1    | | 832.13 |
| EUR004 | |   1    | | 231.37 |
| EUR004 | |   1    | | 231.37 |
| EUR004 | |   2    | | 263.92 |
| EUR004 | |   1    | | 131.96 |
| B&T001 | |   1    | | 929.83 |
| B&T001 | |   1    | | 929.83 |
```

How do I go about combine lines? For example I would like to put all lines for the same companies together like this example:

```
| NTE001 | |   3   | | 304.58  |
| EUR004 | |   7   | | 3223.05 |
| B&T001 | |   2   | | 1859.66 |
```

EDIT: If you are down voting please let me know how I can improve this question!

Comment: SELECT company,SUM(AMOUNT),SUM(total) FROM (your query here) x GROUP BY company

Answer (score 0):

so you want something like:

```
    SELECT company, 
           count(amount) amount, 
           sum (total) total  
      FROM cscart_order_details
INNER JOIN cscart_orders
        ON cscart_order_details.order_id = cscart_orders.order_id
     WHERE date(FROM_UNIXTIME(`timestamp`)) >= ADDDATE(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL -6 DAY)
  GROUP BY company
```